# With SharePoint/InfoPath: Is it possible to switch default views, and then save this setting with a button?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, infopath

So lets say that I have two views, one that is the default and another that can be triggered with a button. Is it possible to switch views, then have the view that you switched to become the default view? So that if the form were opened again it would still be on the view you switched to?

If not, is there a way to have a part of a form read-only to a certain group in SharePoint and editable to another group?

Or even better, could I have an email sent out to with different views to different people?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to set the default view with a button/code. You'd want use a different approach (something similar to the [State Machine Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern))

Create a "State" field, that represents the actual state of the form (usually the same as the views). So when the button is pressed, it sets the State-field to "View2" and switch the view to View2. In the form load rules (Data - Form Load) you create a new Rule that changes the view based on the value State-field.

Yes, setting different section of the form to read-only for specific groups is also possible, however it requires custom code. For each section create a new field (like "Section1Enabled"). Then create a new conditional formatting rule that disables Section1 if Section1Enabled is false. In your form's load event, you add code that that decides whether the current user is in the specific group or not and based on that, you set the value of Section1Enabled.

You can do with SharePoint's [UserGroups.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774345%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or with the SharePoint Server Object Model (google should help you out with that).